# Is there a simple and quick way to preview XAML that lives within a resource dictionary?

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, expression-blend

I have a bunch of XAML assets within a resource dictionary (icons in this case). Each one (so far) is a grid within a viewbox and these are used throughout a WPF application.

I was just wondering if anyone knows of a simple way to preview either individual assets or all assets within the dictionary (in Visual Studio, Blend or some other tool)?

Comment: http://www.kaxaml.com/ ... you might have to wrap in a Page or Window element to display them...put certainly a good tool to do adhoc XAML.

Comment: In Visual Studio you should have Document Outline Window when you hover over an element it will display thumbnail of the element.

Comment: I just use Blend, click the "Resources" tab in the top right corner by default. Expand the dictionary you want to interact with, click the one you want to see and it will render in your design area.

Comment: The document outline pane is empty for resource dictionaries, and the Blend suggestion didn't work either. I can open the resource dictionary and select one of the icons in the Resources pane, but nothing is previewed. I'll have a look at kaxaml.com ..